# Is there a way I can blank pad a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have a string like this:

```
var myString = "abc";

or 

var myString = "a";
```

Is there a way that I can pad the string with spaces so it's always has a length of ten?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(str.length < 10) str += ' ';
```

that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
while(myString.length < 10) {
    myString += " ";
}
```

Comment: off by one. asdfasfdsa